# Assign a product name based on the conditions given in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to write a sql query based on the conditions below:

**PRODUCT**

[image: Product Table]

**ORDER**

[image]

The Product Table has 3 columns based on the following query:
**CREATE Product (MasterProduct nvarchar(50), Productkey int, ProductName  nvarchar(50))**

The Order Table has 3 columns based on the following query:
**CREATE Order (MasterProduct nvarchar(50), Orderno int, Productkey int, ParentProduct int)**

**Scenario:**

The 'MasterProduct' column in Product table should be assigned to a **particular order** in Order Table based on the following conditions:

1) If **all the productkeys** in product table for a **specific Master Product** match the order number in Order table

**AND**

The first ProductKey is a parent to its immediate product key in the Order Table

**Example**: The Order Number 'S1' is assigned a Kebab as Master Product for Order Table because product keys 1 and 2 from Product Table both exist in S1 and also product key 1 is a parent product key to product keys 2 and 4.

On the other hand, Order Number 'S2' isn't assigned any master product (NULL) because it only has '1' as product key and '2' is not present else it would be assigned a Kebab.

S3 is also assigned a Subway because it has product keys 30 and 31 from product table present for that order number, and product key 30 that is a parent product is assigned to at least one child product that it '31'.

S4 is not assigned any Master Product although it has all product keys for Subway (30,31) because 30 that is a parent product isn't assigned to any child product.

Comment: What if the products in an order match different master products? And what defines the order to know which one is the first product key in an order? And please don't use images to post sample data. Ideally use `INSERT` statements or at least some text tables.

Comment: The products in an order will be different for master products. So the product key in a order is sorted by OrderLineNumberKey column (haven't included that in the table).

Comment: Then please add `OrderLineNumberKey` to your question. And why aren't the `7` in `'S1'` or the `35` in `'S3'` violating the second condition?

Comment: OrderLineNumber has been added. S1 has product key 7 , but child product that is product key 2 is assigned to product key 1 (parent product for S1) , hence the other doesn't mater. What the main thing is the second product key for an order should always have a parent product for it to be assigned a "Master Product" and for S1 product key 7 in order table is the 4th product. Similar thing implies for S3. I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit convoluted, but here is a working version:

```
declare @p table(MasterProduct nvarchar(50), Productkey int, ProductName nvarchar(50))
declare @o table(OrderLineNumberKey int, Orderno int, Productkey int, ParentProduct int)
insert @p values('kebab',1,'chicken'),('kebab',2,'mayo'),('subway',30,'bread'),('subway',31,'salad')
insert @o values(1,1,1,null),(2,1,2,1),(3,1,4,1),(4,1,7,null)
insert @o values(1,2,1,null),(2,2,9,null),(3,2,14,1)
insert @o values(1,3,30,null),(2,3,31,30),(3,3,35,null)
insert @o values(1,4,30,null),(2,4,31,null),(3,4,39,null)

;with ParentChild as (
    select o.orderno, o.ProductKey as TopProductKey, o.productkey, p.masterproduct
    from @o o
    join @p p on p.productKey=o.ProductKey
    where parentproduct is null
    union all
    select pc.orderno,pc.ProductKey as TopProductKey,o.productkey,p.masterproduct
    from @o o
    join @p p on p.productKey=o.ProductKey
    join ParentChild pc on pc.orderno=o.orderno and pc.ProductKey=o.ParentProduct
    )

select case when HaveAll=1 then ordercheck.masterproduct end as masterproduct,
    o.orderno, o.productkey,o.parentproduct
from @o o
left join(
    select orderno, masterproduct, max(HaveAll) as HaveAll from (
        select pc1.orderno, p.masterproduct, min(case when pc2.productkey is null then 0 else 1 end) as HaveAll
        from ParentChild pc1
        join @p p on p.masterproduct=pc1.masterproduct
        left join ParentChild pc2 on pc2.orderno=pc1.orderno and pc2.MasterProduct=p.MasterProduct and pc2.productkey=p.productkey and pc2.topproductkey=pc1.topproductkey
        where pc1.TopProductKey=pc1.ProductKey
        group by pc1.orderno, p.masterproduct, pc1.TopProductKey
        ) q
        group by orderno, masterproduct
    ) ordercheck on ordercheck.orderno=o.orderno
```

To explain it, firstly in the CTE we look recursively through the orders looking for all possible parents with a null parent, and finding all their child rows. You will see that order 4 has 2 possible candidates which complicates things.

Then in the main query, there is an inner sub query that compares the all the parent+child rows against the product model, and checks that we have all products. It has to do this for each of the candidate parents, and then rolls that up a second time for the overall order. It has to do this in case there were two candidate parents, one of which was satisfied and one wasnt.

Finally we join this to the orders to return the masterproduct if we had all the products, or null if we didnt.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the query. I ran the query but the master product is assigned NULL to everything. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Did you run with my sample data or your actual data? I just cut and pasted the solution into a query window and it ran fine.